# hash strings get improperly encoded

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ruby-1.9

I have a simple constant hash with string keys defined:

```
MY_CONSTANT_HASH = {
'key1' => 'value1'
}
```

Now, I've noticed that `encoding.name` on the key is `US-ASCII`. However, `Encoding.default_internal` is set to `UTF-8` beforehand. Why is it not being properly encoded? I can't `force_encoding` later, because the object is frozen at that point, so I get this error:

`can't modify frozen String`

P.S.: I'm using ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [internal](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#method-c-default_internal) and [external](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external) encodings are aimed at IO operations:

- CSV
- File data read from disk
- File names from Dir
- etc...

The easiest thing for you to do is to add a `# encoding=utf-8` comment to tell Ruby that the source file is UTF-8 encoded. For example, if you run this:

```
# encoding=utf-8
H = { 'this' => 'that' }
puts H.keys.first.encoding
```

as a stand-alone Ruby script you'll get UTF-8, but if you run this:

```
H = { 'this' => 'that' }
puts H.keys.first.encoding
```

you'll probably get US-ASCII.

Comment: Is this an official way of setting encoding for inline strings? Also, under the link you can read the following: "The locale encoding (__ ENCODING __), not default_internal, is used as the encoding of created strings."

Comment: @m33lky: I think the "magic comment" hack is as official as it gets, there are a few other variations on it as well. The only problem with depending on the locale settings is that they're external to the application or source file so you can get strange non-local effects if you change your locale, work from a different machine, forget to set the locale on a server, ...